# Regex expression to validate invalid url charcters

Tags: javascript

Can you help me to find Regex expression to validate invalid characters in a url string? Everything I found in the internet is having `http/https` validations. That shouldn't be the case. I need just a url string to validate invalid url characters(such as `$,},{,-,etc..`)

Comment: An URL is made up of multiple components (scheme, host, path, query, anchor). Each of these components has its own rules.

Comment: Do you want to include Unicode characters too?

Comment: FYI: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rex/vignettes/url_parsing.html and https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Comment: I only want to validate invalid characters such as "!,$,+,(,),",-" in this. I don't want to validate http:// or https:// or any kind of urls patterns there as I am amending the prefix if user hasn't entered. I only want to validate these invalid special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works fine for me:

```
[^\w\.@-\\]
```

if you want to allow character simply add these into the regex...for example if you want to allow "%" become:

```
 [^\w\.@-\\%]
```

Comment: Thanks. But this url shouldn't be validating http:// or https:// or www or any kind of url patters. I only need to validate invalid charters. Your regex validating http:// and https://  as well

Comment: yes but you asked to check invalid character in URL...and url is composed by http https etc...

Comment: I only want to validate invalid characters such as "!,$,+,(,),",-" in this string. I don't want to validate http:// or https:// or any kind of urls patterns there as I am amending the prefix if user hasn't entered. I only want to validate these invalid special characters for a url.

Comment: check edited answed

Comment: glad that this help, you can accept the answer, so it can be useful for other people

Answer (score 0):

(\b(https?|ftp|file)://)?[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~*|!:,.;]+[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~*|]

Comment: Thanks. But this url shouldn't be validating http:// or https:// or www or any kind of url patters. I only need to validate invalid charters